# Creating a workspace only in Angular is failing due to dependency tree error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new workspace-only project using `Angular CLI 11.0.2` under `Node 12.19.0`, `NPM 7.14.0` according to the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects):

```
ng new cool-workspace --create-application false
```

But when I create it, it always fails due to a dependency tree issue as follows:
[image]

I'm not really sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

EDIT: As requested in the comments, the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "cool-workspace",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: post your `package.json`

Comment: @dota2pro Posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have `"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0"` in your package.json. But your angular-cli version requires newer version

- Either updated package.json `"jasmine-core": "^3.7.1"` and `"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",`
- Or, downgrade angular cli to the version that supports 3.6
- Or, use `--force` in your ng command to use incompatible version.

Comment: Why would the Angular CLI create and use something that's incompatible with itself? When I create a a new Angular project WITH an app, it's still using the "older" versions `3.6.0 & 1.5.0` and it works. What's different? I'm really trying to understand :(

Comment: Maybe you are creating it under another angular workspace ? if yes, try in a new one.

Comment: So, I have just discovered that I'm using NPM `7.x.x`. Downgrading to `6.14.13` solved all issues. I wonder why there are so much incompatibilities among everything.